# Collapsible bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have problem with my collapsible navbar. It shows collapsible button but not "li" when i click on button.
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NxD9.png)

Here is code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Navbar Collapse</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" href="jquery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyWebsite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" >
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">about</a></li>
     <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="">search</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is all fine. I took the same code in the question and got it working. The only change is I pointed the references to be read from cloud. So I am sure The only problem might be the files you are referencing for including `bootstrap.min.js` and your `jquery`. Check your console window to see if there was any error loading these files.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyWebsite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">about</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">search</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have checked it out but there isn't any issue with loading these files

Comment: Try to use the same `src` which I have used in the above snippet.. If it works then may be you need to consider updating your local files with latest one.. Something might have changed there..

Comment: @Zain glad I could help you.. Also if this fixed your issue can you please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You missed out `<div class="navbar-header">` plus `navbar-brand` usually goes after toggle navigation. If that doesn't help I have know idea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Navbar Collapse</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" href="jquery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyWebsite</a>
            </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" >
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">about</a></li>
     <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="">search</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a responsive Bootstrap navbar that toggle-slides out from the left and tracks your scroll.  It can be further customized with media queries for best results on landscape/smallest screens

http://codepen.io/TheNickelDime/pen/NppZdQ

in action:  http://cathairapocalypse.com

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->

<div id="ca_sidenav" class="container-fluid clearfix scrollspy">

    <ul id="ca_nav" class="nav" data-spy="affix">

       <li><a id="ca_nav0" class="CA_navButton active" href="#ca_section0" onclick="navButtonClick(0);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section0</B2></span></a></li>
       <li><a id="ca_nav1" class="CA_navButton" href="#ca_section1" onclick="navButtonClick(1);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section1</B2></span></a></li>
       <li><a id="ca_nav2" class="CA_navButton" href="#ca_section2" onclick="navButtonClick(2);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section2</B2></span></a></li>
       <li><a id="ca_nav3" class="CA_navButton" href="#ca_section3" onclick="navButtonClick(3);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section3</B2></span></a></li>
       <li><a id="ca_nav4" class="CA_navButton" href="#ca_section4" onclick="navButtonClick(4);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section4</B2></span></a></li>
       <li><a id="ca_nav5" class="CA_navButton" href="#ca_section5" onclick="navButtonClick(5);"><div class="CA_navHighlight"></div><span><B2>Section5</B2></span></a></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```