# Make Responsive Navigation Bar

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on web-development project. I can not make my website responsive for mobile devices.

For desktop, the navigation bar looks right, for mobile devices nav-bar does not collapse.

Below snippet is the navigation bar from W3Schools examples-

```
<body>
    <div class="nav navbar"  body {background-color:#000000;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;color: red;} >
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a class="t1" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_google_search">Search</a>
            </li>
```

..
..

```
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_google_search" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <iframe id="google_search" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling = "yes"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What are the possible changes to be made to work my website for mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You want to make collapsible navigation bar. It is called media query, by which the website nav-bar is sized against screen.

Bootstrap is the best tool for making **responsive** website. For Bootstrap you do not require media query, and this framework is designed for speed-up development process. 
The below snippet is copied from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36819594/10531665), only for understanding purpose.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyWebsite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">about</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">search</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run the snippet in full-screen, to avoid **mobile-view** of the website

Comment: I tried that syntax, but it didnt work for me, If I try to add another div or change the class name from na navbar to "collapse navbar-collapse"

Comment: You can not change the BootStrap class name, you can override it. You should not make BootStrap and CSS clash. And follow some guides to make it more clear. If you're answered accept it. For another query, ask a different question.

Comment: I have similar code, can you please update my syntax or guide me which class I need to change or which div I should add with what class name to make it work, I am trying similar, but my page reacts wierdly upon my edits

Comment: Please ask a different question

Comment: okay, but why, I am talking about the same question, you shared a snippet available in google first index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My WebsiteName</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When the screen size reaches equal to the mobile device, this navbar will get converted to a collapsible navbar with three horizontal lines within.

**Note:** I have used Bootstrap v4.0 (latest framework).

Hope this helps.